# Jquery Cycle and Ajax Captions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-cycle

I'm using Jquery Cycle to fade some images being loaded by Ajax, and show a caption for corresponding images using the `onBefore` option in the plugin. The fading portion of this is working fabulously. The caption portion is *sort of* working, only instead of loading just the captions for the current set of images, it loads the captions *and* between each image transition flashes a random caption for an image belonging to a previously loaded set of images.

I tried setting the caption loading to both `before:` and `after:` in the plugin options without luck, and I've tried using `.empty()` to clear the caption container before loading a new caption. Still no good. Jquery Cycle is being called as the success function of the Ajax plugin I'm using with my CMS; I'm guessing the caption problem has something to do with Jquery Cycle being called multiple times, but even destroying Jquery Cycle prior to starting a new instance of it didn't help the caption problem. Here's what my Jquery Cycle function looks like:

```
<!--calls jquery cycle after smd_ajax pulls in the content-->                  
function ajaxcycle(){ 
    $('#full-wrap').cycle({
        after: onBefore 
    }); 

    function onBefore() { 
        $('.caption')
            .empty()
            .html('Opposite: ' + this.alt); 
    }; 
};
```

And [here's the live site](http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/) so you can see what's happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`onBefore` should be defined before you set the .`cycle({})` parameters.

```
var ajaxcycle = function(){ 
    var onBefore = function(){
        $(".caption").empty().html("Opposite: " + this.alt);
    };

    $("#full-wrap").cycle({ after: onBefore });
};
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. The documentation for Jquery Cycle actually does call for onBefore and onAfter to be standalone functions, not variables within functions. The "Callbacks" section on this page shows a demo: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html